# Data truncated for column - return fatal error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I get this error in my error log.

```
Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column ...
```

How to configure mysql to return a fatal error on this kind of warnings?

Mysql 5.6.27

## cnf

```
sql_mode
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to upgrade to 5.7 or MariaDB to get STRICT_TRANS_TABLES to give you an error (and abort the transaction) for that situation.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql_mode/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html